# Invalid operands to binary expressions ("id" and "int")

Tags: objective-c

I'm using the GPUImage framework to take the average red values of some camera input. I'm storing all of the average red values in an array, and I'm trying this:

```
NSMutableArray *redValues = [NSMutableArray array];
__block int counter = 0;

GPUImageVideoCamera *videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

GPUImageAverageColor *averageColor = [[GPUImageAverageColor alloc] init];
[averageColor setColorAverageProcessingFinishedBlock:^(CGFloat redComponent, CGFloat greenComponent, CGFloat blueComponent, CGFloat alphaComponent, CMTime frameTime)
 {
     NSLog(@"%f", redComponent);
     [redValues addObject:@(redComponent)];         
     counter++;
 }];

for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    redValues[i] *= 255; // errors occurs here
}
```

Comment: By the way, it seems that you will be receiving `redComponent` here as a value between 0 and 1; that means that when you store it with `numberWithInt:`, you'll truncate almost all values to 0. Multiplying by 255 later will not help much. Why not `[redValues addObject:@(redComponent * 255)]` directly? You will also be eliminating the loop later...

Comment: @ItaiFerber Please post this as an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: Why do you add `counter` to your `redValues` array? That won't work at all. You need to add `redComponent`. `[redValues addObject:@(redComponent)];`.

Comment: And if you want the average? Why add each red component to an array? Just keep a running total and divide by `counter`. No need for an array.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for the first comment, that completely slipped my mind. As for your second comment, I think I was a bit inarticulate in my question. Each of the redValues being printed by the block is **already** the average red value of a frame from the camera input. Thus, all the elements in redValues are already averages. The only real question I had was on how to multiply all the elements of redArray by 255.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get is because you are trying to multiply an `NSNumber` by an `int`. However, there is a deeper logical issue in that you are receiving `redComponent` as a value between 0 and 1. When you convert to an `int`, you truncate almost all values to 0 (at which point multiplying by 255 will not help much). Instead, you should inline the multiplication (and eliminate the second loop):

```
averageColor.colorAverageProcessingFinishedBlock = ^(CGFloat redComponent, CGFloat greenComponent, CGFloat blueComponent, CGFloat alphaComponent, CMTime frameTime) {
     NSLog(@"%f", redComponent);
     [redValues addObject:@(redComponent * 255)];
};
```